# How to get parent props in child component when using styled component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, styled-components

Let me illustrate with an examble

```
//NavLink: react router component

const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  color: red;
  background: blue;
`
function styledLink(label, to) {
  return <StyledNavLink
    to={to}
    className={(props) => console.log(props)}
  >
    {label}
  </StyledNavLink>
}
```

Here nothing is printed...
If I use `NavLink` instead of `StyledNavLink`, I get all the prop values in console.
Then how to get `NavLink` properties in `StyledNavLink` component?

Comment: What props are you trying to access? What version of `react-router` are you using? Is `styledLink` supposed to be a React component?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are trying to get in the function. The [v5 `NavLink`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) component's `className` function only receives an `isActive` value, and the [v6 `NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink) component's `className` function only receives an `isActive` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The `className` prop of the `NavLink` component is conflicting with the `className` prop used by `styled-components`. The `styled(NavLink)` component will only ever have a stringified `className` prop whereas the `NavLink` component can take either a string or function `className` value.

## Solution

Pass the `NavLink` `className` prop under a different prop and handle the conditional logic in the styled component.

Example:

```
const StyledNavLink = styled(({ className, navLinkClassName, ...props }) => (
  <NavLink
    {...props}
    className={(props) => {
      let extraClass =
        typeof navLinkClassName === "function"
          ? navLinkClassName(props)
          : navLinkClassName;
      return [className, extraClass].filter(Boolean).join(" ");
    }}
  />
))`
  color: red;
  background: blue;

  &.activeLink {
    color: green;
    background: lightgreen;
  }
`;
```

Usage:

```
function styledLink(label, to) {
  return (
    <StyledNavLink
      to={to}
      navLinkClassName={(props) => {
        console.log("styledLink", props);
        return props.isActive ? "activeLink" : null;
      }}
    >
      {label}
    </StyledNavLink>
  );
}

...

{styledLink("home", "/")}
```

If you meant for `styledLink` to actually be a React component:

```
function StyledLink({ label, to }) {
  return (
    <StyledNavLink
      to={to}
      navLinkClassName={(props) => {
        console.log("StyledLink", props);
        return props.isActive ? "activeLink" : null;
      }}
    >
      {label}
    </StyledNavLink>
  );
}

...

<StyledLink to="/" label="home" />
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-parent-props-in-child-component-when-using-styled-component-in-react]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing the props from the parent into your styled component. It should be somewhat like this -

```
const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  color: red;
  background: blue;
`;

const Menu = (props) => {
  const { label, to } = props;
  return <StyledNavLink to={to}>{label}</StyledNavLink>;
};
```

Comment: This is *exactly* how the OP is passing `to` to the `StyledNavLink` component as a prop and wrapping `label` as a child. OP is trying to access *something* in the `className` prop.